# How to pass the user control object to content of another user control?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, user-controls

I'm making a snake game in WPF C# and I created a few user controls for different "views", it means I have the MainWindow which
inherits from the Window class and several user controls with their xaml files. 
One user control represents the main menu, another represents option view and so on.

```
public partial class MainWindow: Window
{
    public static Menu menu;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        menu = new Menu();
        this.Content = menu;
    }
}
```

like above, in MainWindow I create Menu object (it's a one of the user controls - class and xaml file) and set the content of Window to content of Menu. And then in menu class I do the same, for example like user click on button with text "options", he goes to options user control. I just do

```
this.Content = new Options(); //"this" is now menu class
```

when he clicks the button with text "singleplayer", he goes to user control with singleplayer game

```
this.Content = new Game();
```

and so on.
In this way everything works fine, I can switch between different user controls and "load" different contents to application Window, but every time I create new object and it's the problem. When I go to options and then back to menu, a new object of menu class is creating, I cannot remember the previous settings and etc. I would like to create this only once and then reference to this - load existing object content. I tried using binding but it doesn't work. 
Ho can I do this? How can I switch between different user controls without data loss and creating new object every time?

Comment: For example in options I can set something, I can choose a snake texture body or set sounds on/off and everthing
is displayed dynamically, it means I have some pictures which changing when I change the body texture, some sliders etc. So I can goes to options, set something, then back to menu, and again goes to option but now everything is reset, because I create new options object, I would like to save this, I think it's enough to create every single object only once and then just load the proper content due to which button was pressed. How can I do it?

Comment: and another thing is pass the data from options user control to the game class (it's another user control). For example, I choose snake speed in options and I have to see this value in Game class ...

Comment: By making them [singletons](https://jlambert.developpez.com/tutoriels/dotnet/implementation-pattern-singleton-csharp/) (ty Jon Skeet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [singletons](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx).

Singletons allow you to have only one instance of a *class*. This way, every time you manipulate the instance, you manipulate the same one. This allow you to keep / update the state of the same instance through your code.

It's looking like this, and it's thread safe.

```
public sealed class YourClass
{
    private static readonly YourClass instance = new YourClass();

    /* Explicit static constructor to tell C# compiler
     * not to mark type as beforefieldinit */
    static YourClass()
    {

    }

    private YourClass()
    {

    }

    public static YourClass Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: OP's mistake was to set Content of the usercontrol istelf insteand of MainWindow usercontrol. You can get the current window containing usercontrol by using this line of code inside usercontrol.

```
Window yourParentWindow = Window.GetWindow(this);
```

Comment: I did a menu class like a singleton, but now I start the game (everything's ok, the object of menu class is creating), goes to options, but when I trying return to menu I get this error: "Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException.
An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll".

Comment: Maybe the error occurs because I have different xaml files?

Comment: Maybe.. At least, a stackoverflow exception means that something is calling himself, check the call stack

Comment: I did Menu class like a singleton, in MainWindow constryctor I do "Content = Menu.Instance" - object of menu class is creating and put into Window content, game works. Then I goes to options (click the proper button in menu) and then I want to go back to menu (click the proper button for that) and in this moment the StackOverflowException occurs.

Comment: In Options class, in button event function I have " Content = Menu.Instance" - like in MainWindow, so because it's a singleton, the new object of Menu isn't creating (it was created in MainWindow), we get reference to the exsisting object and put it into the current content, so where is the mistake?

Comment: I see. Again try to check the stack / debug to see what is really calling the call loop

Comment: I got "the maximum number of stack frames supported by visual studio has been exceeded"

Comment: In Options class, are you calling `Content = Menu.Instance` ? Because you need to set `MainWindow.Content = Menu.Instance` or you will set the option's content to Menu instance

Comment: Yes, I calling "Content = Menu.Instance" in Options class and of course at the beginning in MainWindow, so how to do that?

Comment: I cannot do MainWindow.Content - it says "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property 'ContentControl.Content'"

Comment: Oops yeah it's wpf i've forgot `Window.GetWindow(this).Content = Menu.Instance`

Comment: It works! Thanks :) Although I wonder if there is some better way to do it, it means maybe I should make another structure of that without a few xaml files etc. Now in each case I pass the whole content between classes, maybe I should use MVVM template or something ... for now I will leave it in this form (with Window.GetWindow(this).Content).